# One of my posts is displayed as page

Tags: posts, permalinks, pages

I rebuilt a website (I dont know, if the rebuilt has something to do with the problem. It has a whole different database, just the url is the same. the post existed on the old page as well). One of my posts is displayed as a page (I can tell by the class .page).

If I change the permalink from /loriotabend to /loriot-abend it works, but /loriotabend is still available and looks odd.

This is the post, as it should look:

http://www.regensburgerturmtheater.de/loriot-abend/

This post doesn't even exist in the backend:

http://www.regensburgerturmtheater.de/loriotabend/

I would not bother, but Google hasn't indexed the site at the moment, so there is still a link, pointing to /loriotabend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that http://www.regensburgerturmtheater.de/loriotabend/ page is an attachment view page. I recommend you just change the name of this http://www.regensburgerturmtheater.de/wp-content/uploads/Loriotabend.jpg photo to different (in admin panel).